# Allow two services to bind to port SSL 443 on different IPs?

Tags: iis, ssl, bind

I have an IIS machine with three IPs, 192.168.5.10 - .12. I'm running two different SSL-based sites on .10 and .11, port 443. Everything is fine.

I've now installed another web server onto my machine and am trying to get it to listen on port 443 on the .12 IP address. Unfortunately IIS and the other server refuse to cooperate, even though the IPs being bound are different. They both think there's a conflict with that port.

Is there any way to get IIS to play nice with the other server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting scenario, you need to tell IIS to not bind to 192.168.5.12.
You can check with netsh if IIS is bound to that IP.

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20101015045113/http://microsync.net/web-server/run-iis-and-apache-webserver-on-same-machine-on-same-port-80.html) is a blog entry which does exactly what you also try.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I must admit it's pretty obscure though. I explicitly told IIS to only listen for HTTP requests on the .10 and .11 addresses. The other server works just fine now on the .12 with SSL.

Comment: I realise that this is a 12yo post, but it addresses exactly my problem. It's unfortunate that the link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

I've had exactly this difficulty running PRTG over SSL on a machine also running IIS. The solution is to explicitly tell IIS exactly which IP addresses it's allowed to use, thus stopping it interfering with services on other addresses.

Specifically, use this at the command line:

```
netsh http add iplisten=192.168.5.10
netsh http add iplisten=192.168.5.11
```

This should prevent IIS and the other service interfering with each other and allow SSL for all services.